# Relational Division in SQL

Tags: sql

Writing a SQL query to list the fullname ('<first_name> <last_name>') of every actor who acted in every film which had a title starting with 'CHOCOLAT':

[image]

Here is my approach:

```
SELECT 
    actor_id, first_name || ' ' || last_name AS fullname
FROM 
    Actor A
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT film_id
                FROM Film F
                WHERE title LIKE 'CHOCOLAT%'
                EXCEPT
                SELECT film_id 
                FROM Film_Actor FA
                WHERE FA.actor_id = A.actor_id)
ORDER BY 
    fullname
```

The problem with this approach is that when there is no film which had a title starting with 'CHOCOLAT%', it lists all the actors instead of returning an empty table.

Comment: Sorry - I misunderstood your question initially. I now understand your approach way better. But then, I don't fully understand your requirement. When there is no film with chocolat in the title, all actors have acted in all of these films. From this point of view, your result is correct. Or should this be treated as a special case?

Answer (score 0):

The query selects the matching films and removes for each actor the film that the actor acts in. If a film remains, the actor is not acting in the film so he must not be present in the final result.

```
SELECT actor_id,
       first_name || ' ' || last_name AS fullname
FROM Actor A
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT film_id
                 FROM Film F
                 WHERE title LIKE 'CHOCOLAT%' -- select all matching films
                 EXCEPT
                 SELECT film_id
                 FROM Film_Actor FA
                 WHERE FA.actor_id = A.actor_id -- remove the films the actor acts in
) -- have a set of films the actor does not act in
-- if there is no matching film the actor does not act in,
-- (i.e. he acts in all of them) he needs to be selected
  and (SELECT count(film_id)
       FROM Film F
       WHERE title LIKE 'CHOCOLAT%') > 0 
-- special case, when there is no matching film at all: 
-- The list of films the actor does not act in would be empty for every actor
-- Thus, the result would be all actors
ORDER BY fullname;
```

Basically, you could just add another if-clause that requires at least one matching film to be present. You could do this with `count() > 0` or `exists(...)`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately, it does not work with larger dataset. Also it needs to be a relational devision.

Comment: OK, I updated my answer, please review :)